# Struts 2 OGNL s:iterator vs JSTL c:forEach performance

Tags: jsp, struts2, jstl, ognl

I've been building some fairly dynamic web applications recently that rely heavily on database(JPA) backed configurations. These applications are multi-user, multi-account systems in which the end users can create custom forms based on JPA entities.

I noticed as my JSP pages became more complex that my performance and load times were taking a hit. Originally I had thought it was the data layer causing my bottleneck, but on a whim today I replaced a couple include pages which are created on the fly using lists of objects that are iterated over by struts with a JSTL based iteration scheme. I was blown away that my page load time went from about 10 seconds to around a second. The render times of the JSP pages increase substantially (with struts2 OGNL iteration) as the list sizes grow.

In my struts configs I have dev mode turned off and I'm using a simple theme set, nothing special. I'm considering rewriting some of my iteration heavy pages to use JSTL instead of struts, but I thought I would ask around to see if I'm missing something or if anyone has run into similar circumstances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OGNL is pretty slow; newer versions will be looking to make some performance enhancements.

IMO where S2 and JSTL tag functionality overlap, as with S1, I lean towards JSTL.

Without knowing more about your actual presentation layer, what measures you've taken to [increase performance](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/performance-tuning.html) already, or more details about what your theme templates look like, it's tough to say more.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Dave. I've been through all the docs as suggested by your provided link and have played briefly with the suggested settings to no avail. It sounds like I may have to use JSTL on my pages that are iteration heavy as they are the only ones that appear to be a bottleneck. I use simple themes and build all my JSP presentation with pure HTML/CSS so there shouldn't be any hang ups there. I'll just split off my iteration sections as includes and mark them up with JSTL instead.

Comment: I would. The poor performance of OGNL has been a sore point with us for some time. An attempt to make the EL engine replaceable was started (we were targeting MVEL) but I don't think that ever got rolled in to any releases... it may be something we look at pretty carefully, though.

Comment: Just ran across this while doing some research, thought you might find it interesting: http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/using-struts-and-xwork-with-jsp-20-and-jstl-11.html

Comment: There's already a request wrapper that will check the value stack (I don't recall which is checked first, the stack or the normal EL scopes). In other words, you can already use JSP EL to access objects on the value stack. A lot of the docs are left over from the original WW code and very early S2 code. (I'm a Struts committer/Struts PMC member, btw.)

Comment: Good to know. Looks like I have some recoding to do tomorrow. Thanks for the tips Dave.

Comment: No sweat :) If you figure out more performance tips, file a CLA and get edit access to the wiki! Or, now that OGNL's an Apache project, push 'em to make it faster. Or push us to make MVEL available. Or... etc. :)